# c3p0 connection pool is not shrinking

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0

I am using c3p0 connection pool with spring (with plain jdbc, NO hibernate). Here is my config

```
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}"/> 
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/> 
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/> 
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/> 
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/> 
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/> 
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25"/> 
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="0"/> 
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="6"/>         
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" /> 
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false" /> 
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="10"/> 
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select curdate()"/> 
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="5" />    
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="5" />      
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" /> 
    </bean>
```

I do see that connection pool hits max value of 25 connections but there shrinks back never shrinks back when load reduces.

I am missing some config here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the config parameters [maxIdleTime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxIdleTime) and [maxIdleTimeExcessConnections](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxIdleTimeExcessConnections).

If you want to aggressively pare back pool size when load lightens, set a short `maxIdleTimeExcessConnections`. Leave just plain `maxIdleTime` fairly long, so you don't needlessly churn through Connections once your pool has hit `minPoolSize`.

If you don't care so much, then just set `maxIdleTime` and eventually the pool will shrink as idle Connections expire. But for reasonable values of `maxIdleTime`, this will happen slowly.

If neither `maxIdleTime` nor `maxIdleTimeExcessConnections` (nor [maxConnectionAge](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxConnectionAge)) are set, these values all default to zero, meaning Connections never expire, and the pool will only shrink as Connections break and fail tests.